# sonar V.4.3.1 does not start with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube

steps
 - install the server
 - change JDBC URL to point to a new created poststreSQL database (default schema / with sonar user). There the default H2 JDBC URL is disabled, and only activated postgreSQL JDBC URL
 - DB user name and password are still the default (sonar / sonar)
 - When starting the server, I see the tables are created successfully, however the server doesn't start successfully. The below shows up in the log.

--------------- part of the log start -----------

```
2014.06.19 16:18:00 ERROR [jruby.rack]  initialization failed
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: stack depth limit exceeded
  Hint: Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
### The error may exist in org.sonar.core.rule.RuleMapper
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: SELECT       rrt.id, rrt.rule_id as "ruleId", rrt.rule_tag_id as "tagId", rrt.tag_type as "type", rt.tag         FROM rules_rule_tags rrt     JOIN rule_tags rt ON rrt.rule_tag_id = rt.id      WHERE  ((rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=? or rrt.rule_id=?
```

------------- END ----------

The sql select statement keep on going till the below shows up:

--------- START -----------

```
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: stack depth limit exceeded
  Hint: Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
    at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:31) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:98) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:50) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
```

Comment: Weird. That'd usually only happen with recursive function calls or recursive triggers. This doesn't seem to be either. Can you enable `log_statement = all` and `log_min_messages =debug1` in `postgresql.conf`, restart PostgreSQL, re-test and post the resulting log?

Comment: Same problem here. Tried emailing the user list for sonarqube, no response.

Comment: @HaythamMohamed - I just noticed that the SQL statement has 117 repetitions of " OR rrt.rule_id = ?".  When you say it "keeps on going" do you mean that there are even more repetitions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a parse error in PostgreSQL, not an execution error.  Since this is SQL it would be normal for a stack-based parser to be used.  This would naturally use a parser production like

```
conditions ::== boolean_term
conditions ::== boolean_term boolean_op conditions
```

in which each additional boolean_term could cause a stack push/recursion.  With over a hundred 'a = ?' terms, and probably more, that parse stack could get very large.

@HaythamMohamed, any possibility there are 2000 or more repetitions of

OR rrt.rule_id = ?

in this query?

If so you need to change the SQL generation used by Sonar, JRuby.rack, or apache abatis.